# Display multiple csv files in highcharts via input

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, highcharts

I am trying to build a csv-Highcharts Graph on which I can choose files and load them into the graph.
Until now, it's possible to load one csv file into the graph via input

ouput-graph.component.html:

```
<highcharts-chart
    id="container" 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
    [(update)]=updateFromInput
    [oneToOne]="true"
    style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>

<button (click)="update_chart()">Update Chart</button>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" (change)="update_chart($event)">
</div>
```

output-graph.component.ts looks like in this snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8ubo3?file=src%2Fapp%2Foutput-graph.component.ts

I built it so that everytime i choose a file and click the "update chart" button, it replaces the graph data with the newly inserted csv file data.

Now, my Idea is to load multiple chooseable csv-files into the graph, so that I can choose a file via input and it will not replace, but add the data to the graph. 
I thought of implementing a loop but got stuck on how I could manage i with the input.

The csv data looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to display the multiple data files in a line diagram, so that i can see the difference between the newer/older data.

Does anyone have any Ideas on how I could make this work or what the best approach would be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional library to parse the CSV files into JSON - like papaparse. Next, you can add data as a default js object and add another series when needed. Check the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-se6d7

Comment: I tried using your code but then got these errors: Cannot find module './data.csv' and    src/app/chart.component.ts(11,1): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("/home/angular-workspace/test-angular-highcharts/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more")' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: Do you have `data.csv` in this path `./data.csv`?

Comment: Yes, I even opened a ticket here and we didn't really find an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953459/import-data-in-angular

Comment: Ok, so i kind of figured out how to use papaparse and tried to implement it your way but i am having problems that the application updates and not replaces the graphs with the input https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-opcho

Comment: I showed you how to add series but this was only an example. You can't add your code with hope that it will work out of the box. Highcharts works correctly the problem is definitely with your code. Try to debug it and you will find the issue for sure.