# Import Data in Angular

Tags: angular

I tried using csv files in my Angular projects like this:

```
import * as data1 from "./data.csv";
import * as data2 from "./data2.csv";
```

They are located in the same folder as the .ts i am trying to use them with.
I got following error:

> Cannot find module 'data.csv'

What I also tried was moving them to the assets folder:

```
import * as data1 from '/assets/data.csv';
```

But the error still shows up.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `import * as data1 from 'assets/data.csv';`

Comment: Where that file is stored? can you show the file directory structure

Comment: i stored them once in the same folder as the ts file which is the app folder and once in the assets folder. tried both. nothing did work

Comment: import * as data1 from 'assets/data.csv'; didn't work either

Comment: @J.Doe Try this:  `import * as data1 from ./assets/data.csv';`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale still the same

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  Can't resolve './assets/data.csv' in '/home/angular-workspace/test-angular-highcharts/src/app'

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfktgp-q5pk6v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the csv file content using HttpClient, for example:

```
constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

readCsvData () {
   this.http.get('path.to.csv')
   .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: `Http` is deprecated and completely removed starting from v8.0.0.  You should use `HttpClient` instead. https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#removed-apis

Comment: how can i access the data using this?

Comment: The first callback in the subscribe get data, so the "data" parameter represents the content of the csv file. If you need to parse it there are libraries which help you work with csv.

Answer (score 0):

on your *.ts* file

```
public csvData: any;

public nColumns: string[] = ['name', 'lastname', 'phone', 'cardId', 'gender'];
```

---

```
public importData() {
    this.csvData.forEach((data: any) => {

      const user: any = {
        name: data.name,
        lastname: data.lastname,
        phone: data.phone,
        cardId: data.cardid,
        gender: data.gender
      };

      this.saveData(user);

    });

  }
```

you can try like this.