# add multiple csv files to the graph with papaparse

Tags: angular, highcharts, papaparse

So, I've tried parsing my csv file which I've got from an input like this:

```
  const jsonData = Papa.parse(documentvalue);
  this.data1 = this.prepareData(jsonData.data);
```

And in my function, i try then to update my graph:
      setTimeout(() => {
        chart.hideLoading();

```
    self.chartOptions.series = [
      self.chartOptions.series[0],
      {
        data: self.data1
      }
    ];

    self.updateFromInput = true;
  }, 2000);
```

But my function does not update the graph with the new data, it replaces the data. How can I update the graph instead of the new data replacing it?

I am trying to use addSeries but i am really struggling how to use it:

```
    self.chartOptions.series = [
    self.chartOptions.series[0],
    {
      data: self.data1
    }
  ];
  self.chart.addSeries({
    data: self.data2
  })
  self.updateFromInput = true;
}, 2000);
```

What is the correct way to add a series from a new file to the graph instead of replacing it?

here is a snippet explaining my solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-ni0c3
Like I said, i am struggling to code so that when i choose the file, it adds to the graph and not replaces the old one. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: I showed you an example with adding two series using papaparse here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887506/display-multiple-csv-files-in-highcharts-via-input/57902227#57902227

Comment: Hi!  I tried to Implement what you showed with your answer. In this post i am trying to show that it does not work or did not understand how exactly. My question is what exactly is wrong with the part shown in the codesandbox and how i could improve this. Why doesnt the addSeries here work? why doesnt the approach without addseries work? How would it be done correctly?